# Firfeox 87 on Ubuntu throws TypeError for RTCRtp[Sender|Receiver].getCapabilities

Tags: firefox, webrtc

Is it a bug that Firefox throws a `TypeError` when `RTCRtp[Sender|Receiver].getCapabilities("video")` is executed in the Developer Tools console?

Firefox version is 87.0 with build number 20210318103112 on Ubuntu 20.04.
For comparison, Chrome Version 90.0.4430.40 (Official Build) beta (64-bit) returns the expected object containing `codecs` and `headerExtensions`.

The full error message for `RTCRtpSender.getCapabilities` in Firefox Developer Tools console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: RTCRtpSender.getCapabilities is not a function
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:1
```

A screenshot of the Firefox Developer Tools showing the error and the Firefox version number:
[image: Screenshot showing error in Firefox 87 Developer Tools console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static RTCRtpSender.getCapabilities method isn't implemented in Firefox. If you need to determine codec capabilities you'll need to create an offer and parse the SDP.

Comment: How do you do it exactly? I tried Google but I cannot find anything other than this thread.